# Playing music with Arduino

Tags: arduino, speaker

I try to program a little song played with an Arduino which have 6 speakers attached to. The process should be that I turn on the different speakers on the frequency and count down the duration of the note. If the duration is over, I play the next sound or turn of the speaker. I have defined different arrays for the 6 speakers. Also I have many defines for the note frequencies and also for the durations.

The problem is, that I just get a deep humming but not a tune.

Has anybody a suggestion what could be wrong about the code?

```cpp
#define pause 0
#define c1    32.7
#define cis1  34.6
#define d1    36.7
#define dis1  38.9
...

#define l1 32
#define l2 16
...

#define note 0
#define laenge 1

int myChannels[] = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
int myDuration[] = { 0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0 };
int myPointer[] =  { 0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0 };
const PROGMEM float myPlayList[6][600][2] = {
   // 1st Voice
   {
     { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, l8},
     { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, l8}, { c2, l8}, { g2, 18},
     ...
   }
};

void play( int out, float freq, float len) {
  if (freq > 0) {
    tone ( myChannels[out], freq);
  } else {
    noTone ( freq);
  }
  myDuration[ out] = len;
}

void setup() {
  for ( int channel = 0; channel < 6; channel++) {
    pinMode (myChannels[channel], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  boolean playing = false;

  for ( int channel = 0; channel < 6; channel++) {
    if (myDuration[channel] == 0) {
      if (myPointer[channel] < sizeof(myPlayList[channel])) {
        play( channel, myPlayList[channel][myPointer[channel]][0], myPlayList[channel][myPointer[channel]][1]);
        myPointer[channel]++;
        playing = true;
      } else {
        noTone ( channel);
      }
    } else {
      myDuration[channel]--;
      playing = true;
    }
  }

  if (!playing) {
    delay (10000);
    for ( int channel = 0; channel < 6; channel++) {
      myDuration[channel] = 0;
      myPointer[channel] = 0;
    }
  }

  delay (25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to call the `tone()` function for six individual channels simultaneously. This can't work since the `tone()` function from arduino core library is specified for generating **one tone at a time**. The reason for this is that it utilizes a single hardware timer for generating the square wave.

Here's a non-exhaustive list of ideas on how to achieve what you're trying to accomplish:

1. Make your design monophone. One pin, one speaker, one voice.
2. Utilize `micros()` to generate the squares by hand.
3. Employ Brett Hagman's tone library: https://code.google.com/archive/p/rogue-code/wikis/ToneLibraryDocumentation.wiki#Ugly_Details . This library utilizes more hardware timers, actual number depending on the Atmel chip of your board. Note that you'd need an Arduino with ATmega1280+ chip to be able to drive six pins simultaneously.

On a side note, `tone()` expects two `int` as argument.